# Hide YouTube when open any model/light box

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, lightbox

I have a YouTube video on the center of the page and when I click any link from the side navigation a light box will appear. But in IE this is going behind the YouTube video.

How do I fix this? - I tried setting the Z-index, but no luck.
Is it possible to hide YouTube video when we open a light box?

Thanks in advance

Update:

`(function(){
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('youtube',function(editor){
        return{
            title:editor.lang.youtube.title,
            minWidth:CKEDITOR.env.ie&&CKEDITOR.env.quirks?368:350,
            minHeight:240,
            onShow:function(){
                this.getContentElement('general','content').getInputElement().setValue('')
            },
            onOk:function(){
                var id = params_from_url("v",this.getContentElement('general','content').getInputElement().getValue());
//                var text='';
                var text='';`

```
            this.getParentEditor().insertHtml(text)
        },
        contents:[{
            label:editor.lang.common.generalTab,
            id:'general',
            elements:[{
                type:'html',
                id:'pasteMsg',
                html:'<div style="white-space:normal;width:500px;"><img style="margin:5px auto;" src="'+CKEDITOR.getUrl(CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath('youtube')+'images/youtube_large.png')+'"><br />'+editor.lang.youtube.pasteMsg+'</div>'
            },{
                type:'html',
                id:'content',
                style:'width:340px;height:90px',
                html:'<input size="25" style="'+'border:1px solid black;'+'background:white">',
                focus:function(){
                    this.getElement().focus()
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
})
function params_from_url(name,url)
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( url );
    if( results == null )
        return name;
    else
        return results[1];
}
```

})();

Answer (score 0):

If your youtube video is embedded as an object, you can set `wmode` to `opaque`

```
<object height="390" width="480" wmode="opaque">
```

This will fix most issues.

Otherwise, you can simply hide a list of banned elements when your thickbox opens.

Comment: Hi John, how can we add wmode dynamically, When video is present in the editor and you select any of the functions from CKEditor like add picture image, the opened lightbox hides behind the video.

Comment: if you're doing this in ckeditor, you'll need to switch to source view in the editor and add it as a parameter.

Comment: It still exists when i applied wmode for iframe tag of youtube from firebug.

Comment: It doesn't go to the iframe tag, it has to go to the `<object>` tag. If you're using iframes, you'll need to hide it on load. Or set the `wmode` tag to the `object` _inside_ the iframe

Comment: Yeah got it, but john My bad how can i apply this wmode dynamically when selected youtube, iam using plugin in ckeditor.

Comment: It's a bit tricky. If you expect an iframe to be there, you can get that iframe and apply the tag to the object. `self.frames["iframeName"]` would give you the iframe. And from there on you can access the DOM like a normal element

Comment: My bad, could you please explore me with an example please, i need this in two scenarios 1.In FCkeditor 2. On Show page when opening light box for a page having youtube video. thanks

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/ Once you get a reference to the iframe, you can find the `<object>` tag in it's DOM and apply the attribute like normal. This highly depends in your scenario. I doubt its possible in FCk because you'd have to trigger the JS code. Much better to just edit your source and change your embed code.

Comment: thanks john will go thru it, but my requirement needs to use plugin only.

Comment: HI john,I directly modified the youtube.js plugin like this and removed iframe tag. var text='<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+id+'?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="390" wmode="opaque"></embed>'; But when i click on OK , the editor is diplaying "FLASH" image instead of showing video , how can i fix this ? thanks

Comment: You should edit the plugin to create code that matches youtube's embed code. Have a look at that first

Comment: previously it was this. var text='<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+id+'?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>'; My bad i am bit week in debugging JS.

Comment: that's because that's the new method. You should have a look at youtube embed codes